# scala user define function not working in sparksql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have written a UDF which basically computes whether given IP address is in cidr list. i am able to call my UDF from scala and it works fine but when I call udf from spark sql it was throwing this error. please help me.

```
%spark
def isinlist = (ip:String) => {
  import org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils

  def checkipinrange = (cidr:String,ip:String) => {
    val utils = new SubnetUtils(cidr);
    val isInRange = utils.getInfo().isInRange(ip);
    if (isInRange) {
      true
    } else {
      false
    }
  }
  sqlContext.udf.register("checkipinrange",checkipinrange)

  val query=s"""select * 
                from tag_ip  
                where checkipinrange(tag_ip.cidr, '$ip') """
  val validrange = sqlContext.sql(query)
  if(validrange.count > 0) {
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
}
isinlist("5.9.29.73")
sqlContext.udf.register("isinlist",isinlist)
```

tag_ip is a list of cidr ip ranges . Here isinlist function works fine. But when i call isinlist function from spark sql it shows error below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at $line926276415525.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$isinlist$1.apply(<console>:198)
at $line926276415525.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$isinlist$1.apply(<console>:184)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
```

can someone help me what is the issue?

Comment: is the above code working? how are you calling isinlist from sql query?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `null` values. For example:

```
val isInRange = ip != null && utils.getInfo().isInRange(ip);
```